# Matlab error - (and maybe others) not assigned during call

Tags: arrays, matlab, function

This is my function (fun1.m):

> function n = F(x)
>
> e=exp(1)
>
> if (-1<=x & x<=0)
>
> ```
>  n=x;
> ```
>
> elseif ( 0<=x & x<=1 )
>
> ```
> n=x.*e.^x;
> ```
>
> elseif (1<=x & x<=3)
>
> ```
>  n=x^3;
> ```
>
> end

if my x=-1:0.01:3

and y=fun1(-0.5) ; y=fun1(0.5) ; y=fun1(2) return correct values, then why

y=fun1(x)

return:

> ??? Output argument "n" (and maybe others) not assigned during
> call to "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\bin\fun1.m>fun1

Help please, I am stuck! I tried simple functions (without ifs/elses) that have array as input, and they are working as intended. Also, if i add to the end of fun1

> else
>
> y=99;

it doesn't give me error, but gives me y=99 response. I think that my input is out of bounds, but I don't know how.

Comment: Well, yes. Your `x` is between -1 and 3, and so it doesn't fall into any of your categories, hence the `99` result.

Comment: Side note: you shouldn't store your own functions under the Matlab program installation itself. You can put them in `My Documents\MATLAB` under your user home directory instead, and they'll be on the path automatically.

Comment: I don't quite understand you am304, x is 1x401 array, and I want resulting y to also be 1x401 array. for first 100 x'es it should be calculated y=x, next 100 should be y=x.*e.^x; and last 201 y=x^3; Can you help me fix my function so it gives me these results? Here's picture of my problem: http://i.imgur.com/PllyjFZ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use && instead of &.

Second, you still may have errors, as your x may be slightly greater than 3 or slightly less than -1 due to precision errors.

EDIT:
I thought you were iterating through values of x:

```
y = [];
for i=1:length(x)
    y(i) = F(x(i));
end
```

Comment: if I do that it gives me error:
??? Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to
logical scalar values.

Error in ==> fun1 at 2
   if (-1<=x && x<=0)

also, I tried x=-0.9:0.01:2.9 but didn't help :(

Comment: @Spawn use && and try calling F for each element in x as show in the edit. However, there is a faster way to implement this in Matlab using vector operations.

Comment: do you mind sharing it with me here? I just got an assignment to do, so if it is easier, shoot! :)